# Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I have a simple html website containing one css and js doc and some images. I need to make this work offline.I use html 5 offline cache for this purpose.
On deploying and browsing i see that the website doesnt cache.Console shows an error :
*Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)*

Following are the details :
Directory structure :
[image]

Manifest file :

[image]

Whats wrong?

Comment: Is it even allowed to use backslashes in a manifest file? I wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name must be manifest.appcache ; it should not contain names of files other than images/javascript/css/html files. Any other types will result in error in fetching files.
The rule applied to offline caching is ~ 'catch all or none'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are caching mobile data on iPhone, please check the filename since, according to Apple Docs it must be **cache.manifest**:

[Storing Data on the Client](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Client-SideStorage/Client-SideStorage.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's already 2019 and I had the very same error message =)

For me renaming the file as `manifest.appcache` made it work.

In any case, digging further about this error, I found the **AppCache API is deprecated** (I'm new to these APIs, since I started studying about **PWA** recently) **and no longer recommended** (Use **CacheStorage** + **ServiceWorkers** instead)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Hope this info can help others on the same path  =)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try example.manifest.php? instead of .txt?

Comment: In a Q&A format, when posting an answer, usually best to make a statement rather than ask a question.